# How best to wait for DialogResult (async)

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's my method

```
private async void OpenDetailWindow()
{
    using (DetailView detailView = new DetailView ())
    {

        DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

        mainView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            result = detailView.ShowDialog();
        }));

        Bitmap img = null;

        if (!detailView.IsHandleCreated) detailView.CreateControl();

        await Task.Run(new Action(() =>
        {
            img = GetAnImage();

            if (!detailView.IsDisposed && result == DialogResult.None) 
            {
                detailView.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    detailView.Image = img;
                }));
            }                                           
        }));

        while (result == DialogResult.None)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            UpdateRecord()
            detailView.Close();
            detailView.Dispose();
            if (img != null) img.Dispose();
        }
        else (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            detailView.Close();
            detailView.Dispose();
            if (img != null) img.Dispose();
        } 
    }
}
```

To briefly explain what's going on , I'm showing a new form that displays an image, but the image might take a few seconds to download so the form is to be displayed first while the image is being downloaded. I've sort of simplified it in a few places and removed some stuff

Because this isn't synchronous, I'm having to wait for some indication of the form being closed. Yes, I need to use `ShowDialog` as I want that behavior

```
while (result == DialogResult.None)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
}
```

This whole while loop to wait for a result seems wrong, but I can't find a cleaner way of doing it. Should I use events instead, or...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of thing is a lot easier if you take advantage of the way `await` returns to the UI thread. So instead of having different threads "send each other updates" and whatnot, you just have the UI thread controlling everything.

In your case, I'd move some of the asynchronous initialization into the `DetailView` class, using some of the ideas from my [article on asynchronous data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) (written with MVVM in mind, but the underlying concepts apply to any UI):

```
public class DetailView
{
  public DetailView()
  {
    // Synchronously load palceholder image.
    Image = <placeholder>;

    // Asynchronously load real image.
    LoadImageAsync();
  }

  private async Task LoadImageAsync()
  {
    try
    {
      Image = await Task.Run(() => GetAnImage());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // TODO: Determine what to do if the image loading fails.
    }
  }

  public Bitmap Image { get; private set; }

  Dispose() { Image?.Dispose(); }
}
```

Then you can use this type as such (assuming `OpenDetailWindow` is called on the UI thread):

```
private async OpenDetailWindow()
{
  using (DetailView detailView = new DetailView())
  {
    var result = detailView.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
      UpdateRecord()
  }
}
```

Comment: And if I didn't want business logic in a view?

Comment: @p3tch: Then move `GetAnImage` into a service object that is passed into your viewmodel constructor.